# Using Leaflet plugin in R

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm using R and RStudio to generate some HTML reports with maps using the leaflet package, and I would like to add a compass to the map using the [leaflet-compass](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-compass) plugin, but don't know where to start. I guess I need to use the `addControl` function, but can't find any examples of how it works and where to install the plugin. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the pull requests https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/pull/181 and https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/pull/171 to see how you might go about adding a plugin.  Or, see the branches with plugins recently added from https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet, such as https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet/tree/plugins/SimpleGraticule.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping for a more straightforward way to do this given the time I have available for doing this, at least I can now safely toss out the idea. I'm still left wondering what is the use case for the `addControl` function though...

Comment: This looks fairly straight forward, I can probably build this out tomorrow.

Comment: Well if you do, please let me know!